# Получить данные с сервера и вывести их на страницу

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, dom, promise

нужно отправит ajax запрос на https://swapi.dev/api/films/ и получить список всех фильмов, так же вывести такие свойства как episode_id, title, opening_crawl и персонажей из свойства characters
characters массив из сылок, я делаю ajax запрос в ajax запросе на персонажей получаю в консоль всех их, как мне вывести их на страницу?
Вот код

```
const dataContainer = document.getElementById('filmDataContainer');

function sendRequest(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(`Something is bad ---> ${e}`)
        });
}

sendRequest('https://swapi.dev/api/films/')
    .then(({results}) => {
        results
            .map(({title, opening_crawl, episode_id, characters}) => {
                    const character =
                        Promise
                            .all(characters.map(url => sendRequest(url)))
                            .then(charactersList => {
                                 charactersList
                                    .forEach(({name}) => {
                                        console.log(name);
                                    })
                            })

                const ulFilmDataList = document.createElement('ul');
                dataContainer.appendChild(ulFilmDataList);

                ulFilmDataList.innerHTML =
                        `<li>Film: ${title}
                             <ul id="filmsData">
                                <li>Episode: ${episode_id}</li>
                                <li>Description: ${opening_crawl}</li>
                                <li>Character name: 
                                     ${//тут должны быть имена персонажей к конкретному фильму}
                                </li>
                             </ul>
                        </li>`
            })
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.error(`Error ---> ${e}`)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const dataContainer = document.getElementById('filmDataContainer');

function sendRequest(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(`Something is bad ---> ${e}`)
    });
}

sendRequest('https://swapi.dev/api/films/')
  .then(({results}) => {
    results
      .map(({title, opening_crawl, episode_id, characters}) => {
        const character = Promise
          .all(characters.map(url => sendRequest(url)))
          .then(charactersList => {
            charactersList.forEach(({name}) => {
              console.log(name);
            });
            const ulFilmDataList = document.createElement('ul');
            dataContainer.appendChild(ulFilmDataList);
            ulFilmDataList.innerHTML =
              `<li>Film: ${title}
                 <ul id="filmsData">
                   <li>Episode: ${episode_id}</li>
                   <li>Description: ${opening_crawl}</li>
                   <li>Character name:
                     ${charactersList.join('<br/>')}
                   </li>
                 </ul>
               </li>`;
          })
      })
  })
  .catch((e) => {
        console.error(`Error ---> ${e}`)
  })
```

Comment: ну этот вариант не подходит, как мы можем вытянуть параметр из then, ```                    <li>Character name:
                     ${charactersList.join('<br/>')}
                   </li>``` characterList.join('<br>') будет undefined или ошибка